# Create sticky button element with Angular material2

Tags: angular, angular-material2, sticky

Url project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcjutu?file=app/bottom-sheet-overview-example.html

[image]
[image]

I want to have a button that opens a `bottom-shet`, positioned on top of it, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to make fixed position for the sticky element. Then use angular to control the display style:

```
[style.display]="divOpenStatus ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

I quickly made a demo at
https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-fixed-bottom-div

Comment: Thank you, I had thought the same thing, only that I wanted to do it 100% with angular material using the bottom sheet element